# kill or detect dynamic stopwatch?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have a dynamic form with different labels generated at run time, when something critical is detected I set the label to blink via this:

```
SoftBlink(label, Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30), Color.Red, 2000, true);

private async void SoftBlink(Control ctrl, Color c1, Color c2, short CycleTime_ms, bool BkClr)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start();
    short halfCycle = (short)Math.Round(CycleTime_ms * 0.5);

    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);

        var n = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds % CycleTime_ms;
        var per = (double)Math.Abs(n - halfCycle) / halfCycle;
        var red = (short)Math.Round((c2.R - c1.R) * per) + c1.R;
        var grn = (short)Math.Round((c2.G - c1.G) * per) + c1.G;
        var blw = (short)Math.Round((c2.B - c1.B) * per) + c1.B;
        var clr = Color.FromArgb(red, grn, blw);

        if (BkClr) 
            ctrl.BackColor = clr; 
        else 
            ctrl.ForeColor = clr;
    }
}
```

this works fine the first pass through the loop but every following loop keeps adding another stopwatch to the label and the blinking goes mad.

what would the best way to kill/ check if blinking is already set on that label and not refire another stopwatch?

I guess I would need to pass what label I'm blinking to the SoftBlink and kill the existing stopwatch somehow in the while true loop?

Comment: Just for sake of curiosity: what's wrong with the `ErrorProvider` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose for a timer and a class that will update the controls. I think it is a bad practice to use awaits within a while loop. How will you ever stop them. It will be more confusing. It's better to add the controls to a list and update them all on a timer. Also, don't set the timer too fast.

Here's an example, I created a new windows forms application and added two labels and two buttons on the form. I created a ItemBlinker class which will track all controls added and update them:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestBlink
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Timer _timer;
        private ItemBlinker _itemBlinker = new ItemBlinker();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // create the timer
            _timer = new Timer();
            _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            _timer.Interval = 10;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // update all blinkers
            _itemBlinker.Update();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // add two labels
            _itemBlinker.Add(label1, Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30), Color.Red, 2000, true);
            _itemBlinker.Add(label2, Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30), Color.Blue, 3000, true);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // remove all blinked controls
            _itemBlinker.Clear();
        }
    }


    public class ItemBlinker
    {
        private Dictionary<Control, BlinkItem> _items = new Dictionary<Control, BlinkItem>();
        private Stopwatch _sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        public void Add(Control ctrl, Color c1, Color c2, short cycleTime_ms, bool bkClr)
        {
            BlinkItem item;

            // if it allready exists, just restore the colors first.
            if (_items.TryGetValue(ctrl, out item))
                item.RestoreColor();

            _items[ctrl] = new BlinkItem(ctrl)
            {
                C1 = c1,
                C2 = c2,
                CycleTime_ms = cycleTime_ms,
                BkClr = bkClr
            };
        }

        public void Remove(Control ctrl)
        {
            BlinkItem item;

            if (_items.TryGetValue(ctrl, out item))
            {
                item.RestoreColor();
                _items.Remove(ctrl);
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            foreach (var item in _items.Values)
                item.RestoreColor();

            _items.Clear();
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            // get the elapsedMilliseconds
            var elapsedMilliseconds = _sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            foreach (var item in _items.Values)
                item.Update(elapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    public class BlinkItem
    {
        private readonly Color _initFore;
        private readonly Color _initBack;

        public Control Ctrl { get; }
        public Color C1 { get; set; }
        public Color C2 { get; set; }
        public short CycleTime_ms { get; set; }
        public bool BkClr { get; set; }

        public BlinkItem(Control ctrl)
        {
            Ctrl = ctrl;
            _initFore = ctrl.ForeColor;
            _initBack = ctrl.BackColor;
        }

        public void Update(long elapsedMilliseconds)
        {
            var halfCycle = CycleTime_ms / 2;
            var n = elapsedMilliseconds % CycleTime_ms;
            var per = (double)Math.Abs(n - halfCycle) / halfCycle;
            var red = (short)Math.Round((C2.R - C1.R) * per) + C1.R;
            var grn = (short)Math.Round((C2.G - C1.G) * per) + C1.G;
            var blw = (short)Math.Round((C2.B - C1.B) * per) + C1.B;
            var clr = Color.FromArgb(red, grn, blw);
            if (BkClr) Ctrl.BackColor = clr; else Ctrl.ForeColor = clr;
        }

        internal void RestoreColor()
        {
            Ctrl.ForeColor = _initFore;
            Ctrl.BackColor = _initBack;
        }
    }
}
```

This way your functionality is much better separated and less spaghetti code. It's easy, with this structure, to kill a blinker. There is even a RestoreColor method to restore the initial colors. (added later)
Also I used a Dictionary to avoid blinking the same control twice.

Answer (score 1):

On the Label's tag property set a flag to indicate whether it's blinking or not.

```
bool? blinking = ctrl.Tag as bool?;

Stopwatch sw;
if (!blinking ?? false)
{
    ctrl.Tag = true;
    sw = new Stopwatch();
    while(true)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    ctrl.Tag = false; // doesn't look like you would ever reach this point.
}
```